# Javascript Tab on Focus

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I currently have the following script that works in the most part however there is a slight modification I would like to make but cannot work how to; I guess with a loop?

**Code:**

```
<script>
    var message = "Come Back";
    var original = document.title;
    window.onblur = function() {
        document.title = message;
    }
    window.onfocus = function() {
        document.title = original;
    }
</script>
```

It currently changes the name of a tab to "Come Back" when focus is lost and then reverts to the original message when the tab is selected again.

I am hoping to add a 2nd "non-focussed" message which the script will switch between every few seconds whilst the tab is not in focus - such as "Come Back", wait 1 second, "Don't Forget".

Comment: I removed the Java tag and replaced it with JavaScript.  These are two entirely different languages.  You'll get better help if you make your tags match your question, because lots of people just watch for the tags for technologies that they know about.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's better to use `window.addEventListener("blur", function() {})` to wait for the blur event, then set a callback function that will run once the window or the tab has lost focus.

For the callback function you should consider using the `setTimeout` global method that sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once the timer expires. In your case let's say we want the title to say first "Come back", then after 3 seconds it'll say "Don't forget", and after another 3 secends "Where did you go?", the callback function will look like this:

```
function() {
  document.title = "Come Back";
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.title = "Don't forget";
  }, 3000); // Runs after 3 seconds of inactivity
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.title = "Where did you go?";
  }, 6000); // Runs after 6 seconds of inactivity
}
```

Another remark is that the focus event handler you implemented replaces the `document.title` by original which is a reference to `document.title` itself and will return the same current title. Instead, the original title should be stored as a hard-coded string and then used to replace the title when the window is focused.

Wrapping everything up, the final code will look like this:

```
<script>
  const original = "Original title";

  window.addEventListener("focus", function () {
    document.title = original;
  });

  window.addEventListener("blur", function () {
    document.title = "Come Back";
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.title = "Don't forget";
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.title = "Where did you go?";
    }, 5000);
  });
</script>
```